# PHP syntax-error, unexpected $EOF on last empty line

Tags: javascript, php, html, syntax, eof

I have to take care of an old website but it was offline because there were errors in the script. In most of the script I got the errors out but with this one I have no idea. My site gives this: syntax-error, unexpected $EOF. On the last line of my script but there is nothing on that line. I've looked on a lot of forums but I couldn't find an answer that works for me. Could somebody look at my code.

```
<?php
/**
* @version $Id: frontend.php 5930 2006-12-06 00:49:07Z friesengeist $
* @package Joomla
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* Joomla! is free software.

 This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*/

defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
/**
* Displays the capture output of the main element
*/
function mosMainBody() {
        global $mosConfig_live_site;
        // message passed via the url
        $mosmsg = stripslashes( strval( mosGetParam( $_REQUEST, 'mosmsg', '' ) ) );

        $popMessages = false;

        // Browser Check
        $browserCheck = 0;
        if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $mosConfig_live_site) !== false ) {
                $browserCheck = 1;
        }

        // Session Check
        $sessionCheck = 0;
        // Session Cookie `name`
        $sessionCookieName      = mosMainFrame::sessionCookieName();
        // Get Session Cookie `value`
        $sessioncookie          = mosGetParam( $_COOKIE, $sessionCookieName, null );
        if ( (strlen($sessioncookie) == 32 || $sessioncookie == '-') ) {
                $sessionCheck = 1;
        }

        // limit mosmsg to 150 characters
        if ( strlen( $mosmsg ) > 150 ) {
                $mosmsg = substr( $mosmsg, 0, 150 );
        }

        // mosmsg outputed within html
        if ($mosmsg && !$popMessages && $browserCheck && $sessionCheck) {
                echo "\n<div class=\"message\">$mosmsg</div>";
        }

        echo $GLOBALS['_MOS_OPTION']['buffer'];

        // mosmsg outputed in JS Popup
        if ($mosmsg && $popMessages && $browserCheck && $sessionCheck) {
                echo "\n<script language=\"javascript\">alert('" . addslashes( $mosmsg ) . "');</script>";
        }
}
/**
* Utility functions and classes
*/
function mosLoadComponent( $name ) {
        // set up some global variables for use by frontend components
        global $mainframe, $database, $my, $acl;
        global $task, $Itemid, $id, $option, $gid;

        include( $mainframe->getCfg( 'absolute_path' )."/components/com_$name/$name.php" );
}
/**
* Cache some modules information
* @return array
*/
function &initModules() {
        global $database, $my, $Itemid;

        if (!isset( $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'] )) {
                $Itemid                 = intval($Itemid);
                $check_Itemid   = '';
                if ($Itemid) {
                        $check_Itemid = "OR mm.menuid = " . (int) $Itemid;
                }

                $query = "SELECT id, title, module, position, content, showtitle, params"
                . "\n FROM #__modules AS m"
                . "\n INNER JOIN #__modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id"
                . "\n WHERE m.published = 1"
                . "\n AND m.access <= ". (int) $my->gid
                . "\n AND m.client_id != 1"
                . "\n AND ( mm.menuid = 0 $check_Itemid )"
                . "\n ORDER BY ordering";

                $database->setQuery( $query );
                $modules = $database->loadObjectList();

                foreach ($modules as $module) {
                        $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'][$module->position][] = $module;
                }
        }
        return $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'];
}
/**
* @param string THe template position
*/
function mosCountModules( $position='left' ) {
        global $database, $my, $Itemid;

        $tp = intval( mosGetParam( $_GET, 'tp', 0 ) );
        if ($tp) {
                return 1;
        }

        $modules =& initModules();
        if (isset( $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'][$position] )) {
                return count( $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'][$position] );
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}
/**
* @param string The position
* @param int The style.  0=normal, 1=horiz, -1=no wrapper
*/
function mosLoadModules( $position='left', $style=0 ) {
        global $mosConfig_gzip, $mosConfig_absolute_path, $database, $my, $Itemid, $mosConfig_caching;

        $tp = intval( mosGetParam( $_GET, 'tp', 0 ) );
        if ($tp) {
                echo '<div style="height:50px;background-color:#eee;margin:2px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #f00;color:#700;">';
                echo $position;
                echo '</div>';
                return;
        }
        $style = intval( $style );

        require_once( $mosConfig_absolute_path . '/includes/frontend.html.php' );

        $allModules =& initModules();
        if (isset( $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'][$position] )) {
                $modules = $GLOBALS['_MOS_MODULES'][$position];
        } else {
                $modules = array();
        }

        if (count( $modules ) < 1) {
                $style = 0;
        }
        if ($style == 1) {
                echo "<table cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
                echo "<tr>\n";
        }
        $prepend = ($style == 1) ? "<td valign=\"top\">\n" : '';
        $postpend = ($style == 1) ? "</td>\n" : '';

        $count = 1;
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
                $params = new mosParameters( $module->params );

                echo $prepend;

                if ((substr("$module->module",0,4))=='mod_') {
                // normal modules
                        if ($params->get('cache') == 1 && $mosConfig_caching == 1) {
                        // module caching
                                $cache->call('modules_html::module2', $module, $params, $Itemid, $style, $my->gid  );
                } else {
                // custom or new modules
                }
                        if ($params->get('cache') == 1 && $mosConfig_caching == 1) {
                        // module caching
                                $cache->call('modules_html::module', $module, $params, $Itemid, $style, 0, $my->gid );
                        } else {
                                modules_html::module( $module, $params, $Itemid, $style );
                        }

                echo $postpend;

                $count++;
        if ($style == 1) {
                echo "</tr>\n</table>\n";
        }
}
/**
* Assembles head tags
*/
function mosShowHead() {
        global $database, $option, $my, $mainframe, $_VERSION, $task, $id;
        global $mosConfig_MetaDesc, $mosConfig_MetaKeys, $mosConfig_live_site, $mosConfig_sef, $mosConfig_absolute_path, $mosConfig_sitename, $mosConfig_favicon;

        $mainframe->appendMetaTag( 'description', $mosConfig_MetaDesc );
        $mainframe->appendMetaTag( 'keywords', $mosConfig_MetaKeys );
        $mainframe->addMetaTag( 'Generator', $_VERSION->PRODUCT . ' - ' . $_VERSION->COPYRIGHT);
        $mainframe->addMetaTag( 'robots', 'index, follow' );

        // cache activation
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

                echo $cache->call('mainframe->getHead', @$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $id);
        } else {
                echo $mainframe->getHead();
        }

        if ( isset($mosConfig_sef) && $mosConfig_sef ) {
                echo "<base href=\"$mosConfig_live_site/\" />\r\n";
        }

        if ($my->id || $mainframe->get( 'joomlaJavascript' )) {
                ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.2.0">
<script src="%3C?php%20echo%20$mosConfig_live_site;?%3E/includes/js/joomla.javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><?php
        }

        $row = new mosComponent( $database );
        $query = "SELECT a.*"
        . "\n FROM #__components AS a"
        . "\n WHERE ( a.admin_menu_link = 'option=com_syndicate' OR a.admin_menu_link = 'option=com_syndicate&hidemainmenu=1' )"
        . "\n AND a.option = 'com_syndicate'"
        ;
        $database->setQuery( $query );
        $database->loadObject( $row );

        // get params definitions
        $syndicateParams = new mosParameters( $row->params, $mainframe->getPath( 'com_xml', $row->option ), 'component' );

        // needed to reduce query
        $GLOBALS['syndicateParams'] = $syndicateParams;

        $live_bookmark = $syndicateParams->get( 'live_bookmark', 0 );

        // and to allow disabling/enabling of selected feed types
        switch ( $live_bookmark ) {
                case 'RSS0.91':
                        if ( !$syndicateParams->get( 'rss091', 1 ) ) {
                                $live_bookmark = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                case 'RSS1.0':
                        if ( !$syndicateParams->get( 'rss10', 1 ) ) {
                                $live_bookmark = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                case 'RSS2.0':
                        if ( !$syndicateParams->get( 'rss20', 1 ) ) {
                                $live_bookmark = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                case 'ATOM0.3':
                        if ( !$syndicateParams->get( 'atom03', 1 ) ) {
                                $live_bookmark = 0;
                        }
                        break;
        }

        // support for Live Bookmarks ability for site syndication
        if ($live_bookmark) {
                $show = 1;

                $link_file      = $mosConfig_live_site . '/index2.php?option=com_rss&feed='. $live_bookmark .'&no_html=1';

                // xhtml check
                $link_file = ampReplace( $link_file );

                // security chcek
                $check = $syndicateParams->def( 'check', 1 );
                if($check) {
                        // test if rssfeed module is published
                        // if not disable access
                        $query = "SELECT m.id"
                        . "\n FROM #__modules AS m"
                        . "\n WHERE m.module = 'mod_rssfeed'"
                        . "\n AND m.published = 1"
                        ;
                        $database->setQuery( $query );
                        $check = $database->loadResultArray();
                        if(empty($check)) {
                                $show = 0;
                        }
                }
                // outputs link tag for page
                if ($show) {
                        // test if security check is enbled
                        ?>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php echo $mosConfig_sitename; ?>" href="<?php echo $link_file; ?>"><?php
                }
        }

        // favourites icon
        if ( !$mosConfig_favicon ) {
                $mosConfig_favicon = 'favicon.ico';
        }
        $icon = $mosConfig_absolute_path .'/images/'. $mosConfig_favicon;
        // checks to see if file exists
        if ( !file_exists( $icon ) ) {
                $icon = $mosConfig_live_site .'/images/favicon.ico';
        } else {
                $icon = $mosConfig_live_site .'/images/' .$mosConfig_favicon;
        }

        // outputs link tag for page
        ?>
```

I know it is a lot of code but if somebody could give me an answer I would be so thankfull.

Comment: Use a code editor with pair matching, you'll find it.

Comment: "Unexpected EOF" usually means there's one or more missing `}` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `mosLoadModules( $position='left', $style=0 )` function . The `foreach ($modules as $module) {` at line 156 doesn't have an ending tag. This issue applies to `if ($params->get('cache') == 1 && $mosConfig_caching == 1) {` at line 163.